# While Running Angular Code which thing first called? Is it first index.js or main.ts or something else?

Tags: angular

As per My Knowledge index.html file is called first and then main.ts, which is used to bootstrap the App Component. Please Suggest!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [which file runs first in an angular 4 app when i run the app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51691628/which-file-runs-first-in-an-angular-4-app-when-i-run-the-app)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Angular looks into angular.json file and checks for which file is defined in 'main' property. So basically, main.ts file is included (By default) in that property. And after that, It goes to main.ts file which bootstraps our AppModule.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of these two files as two different entry points.

`index.html` acts as an entry point for the DOM or the Component Tree.

`main.ts` acts as an entry point for the TypeScript.

These are the files that you specify in `angular.json`:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "demo": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/demo",
            "index": "src/index.html", // Right Here
            "main": "src/main.ts", // Right Here
            ...
          },
          "configurations": {
            ...
          }
        },
        ...
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "demo"
}
```

However, if you see the `index.html` file that gets generated in the `dist` folder, you'll see something like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Your App Name Here</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/your-company-logo.png">
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see, all the JS files, that gets generated after the build are linked in the `script` tags at the bottom. So it would be safe to say that index.html would act as an entry point for the whole App.

The client will receive the whole Application Bundle containing `index.html` and the other js files like `runtime`, `polyfills`, `styles`, `vendor`, `main` etc. These files are generated by the build process which is configured by the `angular.json` file. So once these JS files are loaded, the browser is aware of the contents of `main.ts` file and where the browser can find them.

As of now, the browser won't be aware of the `<app-root></app-root>` tag as the Angular App hasn't bootstrapped yet.

The Angular App would bootstrap once the browser runs **the contents** of `main.ts` file. I saying **the contents** because these TS files are built and the transpiled JS files are run. So I'm not really sure as of now as to where that code goes to after transpilation and building.

Once the Angular App is bootstrapped, and Angular has bootstrapped the Root Component since it was present in the `bootstrap` array of the root `@NgModule`, the browser would then understand what this `<app-root></app-root>` is.

Angular would then also start creating the Component Tree from the RootComponent.

And this is **roughly** how an Angular App bootstraps. I've tried my best to make you understand how it all works.

Comment: Thanks. As I understand that first it will go into angular.js file and there under "Options" property there is few sub properties. There is two property "index" & "main". In "index" it defined index.html file and in "main" it defined main.ts files. As your comments there is two entry points..... Ohhh man I am still confused... Can anyone or you explain in few words. I am beginner to this technology. Please help

Comment: @AshishAhuja, I've updated my answer to help you understand in a better way. Hope this makes it clear.

Comment: Thanks, I have understood the most of this. thanks alot. appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your angular.json file,

you will see something like below.

```
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/TEST",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          "src/assets",
          {
            "glob": "**/*.json",
            "input": "public/",
            "output": "./public/"
          },
          "src/manifest.json"
        ],
        "styles": [         
          "src/styles/styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",

        ]
      }
    }
   }
```

So when you build your angular application, you need to give the base index.html file where you have the  selector which has the code for AppComponent.

In your main.ts you will find the AppModule which bootstraps the application

Comment: Thanks.... Where we have to define  base index.html? Is it in angular.json under "Options" property in that index "options": { "outputPath": "dist/TEST", "index": "src/index.html

Comment: Your index.html should be located under the src directory and you have it put it at the "index" attribute in your options

Comment: It would be better if you post your code on stackblitz and share here