# Can anyone give me a clear idea which runs first, Index.html or main.ts?

Tags: angular

There are many questions on StackOverflow, related to this but none answers with logic.

If Index.html runs first.

Main.ts or better say Main.js (after transpilation) can't run by itself as it is a javascript file at the end, and Index.html file is the one that contains the reference of main.js at the bottom before the closing body tag, obviously, the webpack does all this.

Now, let's say from the configuration that is Angular.json file, the angular knows that Index is the main HTML file that should be served first.

Then again, as Main.js is unknown at this point, so there is no way that the angular would know about the root component. And it must throw an error while parsing  but it doesn't throw the error. This means, it already knows about app-root, which means Main.js is the entry point. But how is this possible, how a javascript file can be triggered without Html page?

first way:- Angular.json ---> Main.js--->Index.html  (but how is this possible? who triggers Main.js?)

second way:- Angular.json--->Index.html---->Main.js (but then how do angular know about  ??)

also,
**My question is, If I write huge "ts" code inside the App-Component itself, then also it will not be executed even after the flow reaches the `<app-root>` as angular has no idea about what `<app-root>` actually is until it finds the Main.js in the body tag and executes it and then only it could know about it.**

Comment: What do you mean by "which runs first"? A HTML file cannot be "run". If you mean network accesses: check your browser's network console

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/q/51691628 resolve your question?

Comment: @NicoHaase, no sir, it doesn't answer my question, the angular documentation says that Main.ts is the file that executes first, how is this possible, until someone points to the Main.js. And if Index loads before (yes with network tab, it is confimed) Main.ts, then<app-root> must be empty at the beginning but is not documented anywhere.

Comment: "<app-root> must be empty at the beginning but is not documented anywhere" - what do you mean by that? What **exactly** should be documented, but is not?

Comment: @NicoHaase Read the answer given by Nenad, it says that When application is opened, initially index.html start to render and it will render with empty <app-root></app-root> ,

Comment: And what's your question about this? Please add all clarifying information to your question by edting it

Comment: @NicoHaase My question is, If I write huge "ts" code inside the App-Component itself, then also it will not execute even after the flow reaches the <app-root> as angular has no idea about what <app-root> actually is until it finds the Main.js in the body tag and executes it and then only it could know about it.

Comment: What makes you think that Angular needs to have any knowledge about `<app-root>`? Does Angular run anything before the other parts? How should it stand in the first place, like you assume in the two possible ways?

Comment: @Bhavna In case you are still not clear how main.ts is triggered. Answer is, when index.html loads on browser, you may check body tag of html. At the end of body tag you would see some imports related to bundles, that is basically our angular code. These imports are added when we build the app. That imported code triggers main.ts. More on this, why Angular documentation says "main.ts is entrypoint". Answer is, You should not get confused with index.html because index.html is served by server, main.ts is served by Angular framework. so this statement is correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can tested it easily. Put `console.log(1)` in the `index.html`, and `console.log(2)` in `main.ts`. First console will be `1`, so `index.html` runs first.

When application is opened, initially `index.html` start to render and it will render with empty `<app-root></app-root>` - because Angular app is still to be loaded (you can test that easily with `CTRL + U` - that is initial content that browser see). That was the big bottleneck for the SEO of SPA apps.

Once the Angular app is loaded, it will dynamically populate the content to the `<app-root></app-root>` of the `index.html`.

**UPDATE**

I missed the part why the `error` is not thrown when `index.html` comes to `<app-root></app-root>` tag. @Ashish explained that really well in his answer (and definitely deserves an upvote), so I will just quote his answer here:

> Reason is, index.html is not an Angular template file, it is pure
> html, you can place any  element inside it and it will never
> throw an error. But for Angular template files, during compile time it
> checks if  is defined or not and throws compile time error if not
> defined.

Comment: but then how does it know about the <app-root> component?

Comment: Yes, initially index.html start to render and it will render with empty <app-root></app-root>, this is what I wanted to hear, I too think the same way, but is not documented anywhere, so I will mark your answer as accepted if others don't argue on this.

Comment: You can test that easily with "CRTL + U". It will open the initial code that browser will see.

Comment: yes sir, I know, I just wanted to confirm it and also why do angular documentation says that main.ts is the entry point and it is where the application starts execution?

Answer (score 9):

As it is clear from Nenad's answer index.html loads first followed by main.js. Once main.js is loaded it renders the root component inside `<app-root>`.

Your main confusion here seems, **Angular encounters `<app-root>` in html before main.js/main.ts is loaded or executed, then why it doesn't throw any error or exception because if main.js is not loaded that means `<app-root>` is not defined yet.**

Reason is, **index.html** is not an Angular template file, it is pure html, you can place any `<xyz>` element inside it and it will never throw an error. But for Angular template files, during compile time it checks if `<xyz>` is defined or not and throws compile time error if not defined.